# What is exe option for batch?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, exe

I need to "translate" or rewrite a old batch file into powershell.

Command is an exe file. It looks roughly like:

> dir1\dir2\XsltTransform.exe -i dir_1\dir_2\blah.xml -x
>   dir_x\dir_y\something.xslt -o path1\path2\result.html

I am a bit confused on the **-i, -x,** and **-o** bit

Also some command even have **-r, -p, -a, -b, -l** as well.

I know they possibly mean option of some sort.

But I just can't seem to find on Google or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code has an EXE file. I am assuming you have access to the source-code from which the EXE was generated.

The `-i -x -o` are all input parameters. *Somewhere within that EXE*, there's some code that *handles* these parameters and stores them into variables.

```
-i dir_1\dir_2\blah.xml -x dir_x\dir_y\something.xslt -o path1\path2\result.html
```

Thus, `dir_1\dir_2\blah.xml` would (probably) get stored into some variable for further processing, and so on.

While reading this answer, read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx) as well. Keep the Microsoft TechNet and MSDN websites handy - it helps :)

To be able to launch a Powershell script with "-x -y"parameters, you need to define the following at the top of your script.

**Basic Usage**

```
Param(
  [string]$x,
  [string]$y
)
```

Here you'd call the script as `script -x -y`

This will accept two arguments -x and -y. Whatever you feed in is stored as a string (in this example), in variables `$x $y`.

If you want any other datatype simply change the `[string]` value.

**Advanced Usage**

- You can also make a parameter have aliases using the `[alias("myalias")]` construct. This helps if you have a long variable name, but need a shorter alias for the commandline usage.
- You can make parameters optional using the `[parameter(Mandatory = $false)]` construct.

e.g.

```
Param(
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[alias("myalias1")]
[string]$mylongvariablename1,

[parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[alias("myalias2")]
[string]$mylongvariablename2,
....
```

In this above example, you would call the script as `script -myalias1 -myalias2` (myalias2 is of course, an optional param).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help
what does 
-i, -x and -o 
mean?
thank

Comment: I edited this answer. Please read the answer again. If the answer is helpful please mark it as answer, or upvote it.

Comment: Hi,I just found the answer by poking around but your answer will help me later on with my powershell scripting!!!

So thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself just now by poking around.

first of all you can to go the directory using

> > help [whatever_command]
> >     it will give you all the options

or sometime you have to use in my case (an exe file)

> > XsltTransform /?